# Preserve word index on TextSelectionChanged

Tags: c#, search, textbox, selection

I've got a find next and previous function and edited it so that when the user selects text in a textbox and clicks on either Find Next or Find Previous button, the find feature will start it's index from the selected character and go through each search result (initially the feature wasn't there). To get the starting index of the selected text I created a function:

```
private int GetIntialCharPos(string Text)
{
    int row = Variables._TextBox.GetLineIndexFromCharacterIndex(Variables._TextBox.CaretIndex);
    int col = Variables._TextBox.CaretIndex - Variables._TextBox.GetCharacterIndexFromLineIndex(row);
    return col;
}
```

The function which does the Find Next and Previous goes as follows:

```
private List<int> _matches;
    private string _textToFind;
    private bool _matchCase;
    private int _matchIndex;

    private void MoveToNextMatch(string textToFind, bool matchCase, bool forward)
    {
        if (_matches == null || _textToFind != textToFind || _matchCase != matchCase)
        {
            int startIndex = 0, matchIndex;
            StringComparison mode = matchCase ? StringComparison.CurrentCulture : StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase;

            _matches = new List<int>();
            while (startIndex < Variables._TextBox.Text.Length && (matchIndex = Variables._TextBox.Text.IndexOf(textToFind, startIndex, mode)) >= 0)
            {
                _matches.Add(matchIndex);
                startIndex = matchIndex + textToFind.Length;
            }

            _textToFind = textToFind;
            _matchCase = matchCase;
            _matchIndex = forward ? _matches.IndexOf(GetIntialCharPos(textToFind)) : _matches.IndexOf(GetIntialCharPos(textToFind)) - 1;
        }
        else
        {
            _matchIndex += forward ? 1 : -1;
            if (_matchIndex < 0)
            {
                _matchIndex = _matches.Count - 1;
            }
            else if (_matchIndex >= _matches.Count)
            {
                _matchIndex = 0;
            }
        }

        if (_matches.Count > 0)
        {
            Variables._TextBox.SelectionStart = _matches[_matchIndex];
            Variables._TextBox.SelectionLength = textToFind.Length;
            Variables._TextBox.Focus();
        }
    }
```

My issue is that once the user has selected the text he needs to search, and goes through the find next and previous buttons, and then he decides to select the text from a different index, rather than continuing the search from the selected index, it will maintain the default initial order which it goes by rather than starting from the selected index and going through each result from that. I created a small [gif video here](http://recordit.co/nMlAxKAIRq) so you can take a better look at this problem.

How do I preserve the selected word index so every time the user selects from a different index it can start the search from the index in which the user selected rather than always starting from the start.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
private int _matchIndex;
```

That's your problem variable.  It retains the last match index but you don't know when the user changes it by himself.  The TextBox class does not have a SelectionChanged event to tell you about it so there is no simple way to reset the variable.

Simply use a RichTextBox instead, it does have [that event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.richtextbox.selectionchanged%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

But it is much easier, this bug occurred because you added state unnecessarily by splitting of the searching operation into a separate class.  State is in general a bad thing, it is a bug generator.  You can trivially make the entire operation stateless by using the TextBox object directly:

```
    private static void MoveToNextMatch(TextBoxBase box, bool forward) {
        var needle = box.SelectedText;
        var haystack = box.Text;
        int index = box.SelectionStart;
        if (forward) {
            index = haystack.IndexOf(needle, index + 1);
            if (index < 0) index = haystack.IndexOf(needle, 0);
        }
        else {
            if (index == 0) index = -1;
            else index = haystack.LastIndexOf(needle, index - 1);
            if (index < 0) index = haystack.LastIndexOf(needle, haystack.Length - 1);
        }
        if (index >= 0) {
            box.SelectionStart = index;
            box.SelectionLength = needle.Length;
        }
        box.Focus();
    }
```

Use the Last/IndexOf() method that takes a StringComparison to implement the *matchCase* argument.

Comment: I'm using a wpf textbox and there is a selection changed event available. But I guess this code would work because I assumed that you you wrote the code not needing to use the selection changed event. I'm out, I'll be testing it and let you know

Comment: How would I loop the findings i.e when I reach the end of a specific highlighted text, and I click either Next or Previous, how can i start searching all over again? at the moment If i keep clicking next, it will end at the final term and if i click previous it throws a Index out of range error.

Comment: That was indeed a bug, fixed and made to wrap.